# convert REST API - json output into table Power BI

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-rest-api

After conversion of json output into table in Power BI.
[image]

However, I'm unable to transform above format into below format in Power BI.

[image: expected result]

Any suggestion how I can solve this problem in Power BI.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [column.lable]="name" then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[column.lable]), "column.lable", "column.value"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]